# Context menu drop down in list datasheet view SharePoint 2013

Tags: 2013, ecb-menu

How to Disable context menu in list datasheet view in SharePoint 2013?

My aim is to disable the rename column name in the Context menu in datasheet view.

Answer (score 1):

It's admittedly a bit of a hack but you could add this CSS to the page (say via hidden Content Editor web part) and it will hide the "Rename Column" option from the column menu:

```
.ms-core-menu-item[text="Rename Column"] {
    display:none
}
```